# Merging two FORTRAN codes

Tags: fortran

I have two FORTRAN codes that are almost identical except for one line of code, and the FILE names in my OPEN statements.  This one different line of code produces the two distinct final results I am looking for hence why I have two different codes.

I would like to merge these two codes into one if possible.

What is the best way to do this? To be specific, I want to have only one FORTRAN file which will run either FORTRAN 'code'. That way, when I need to edit either code I am only doing so in one file.  Now having two different files it is a bit of an inconvenience.

A simplified example code for the two different files are below, Sample.f90 and Sample2.f90.  What IF statements can I use that will allow me to choose which initial condition to use, either R = COS(x+y) or R = SIN(x+y)?  I am not familiar at all with how to use IF statements for this.

```
PROGRAM SAMPLE !Sample.f90

USE TestModule

IMPLICIT NONE

REAL, DIMENSION(-10,10) :: R
INTEGER :: i,j
REAL :: x,y

OPEN(UNIT = 100, FILE = 'Sample1.dat')

DO j = -10,10
DO i = -10,10

    x = i*0.1
    y = j*0.1

        R(i,j) = COS(x+y)

END DO
END DO

WRITE(100,*) R(0,1)

END PROGRAM 

!The next program is of the form:

PROGRAM SAMPLE2 !Sample2.f90

USE TestModule2

IMPLICIT NONE
REAL, DIMENSION(-10,10) :: R
INTEGER :: i,j
REAL :: x,y
OPEN(UNIT = 101, FILE = 'Sample2.dat')

DO j = -10,10
DO i = -10,10

    x = i*0.1
    y = j*0.1

        R(i,j) = SIN(x+y)

END DO
END DO

WRITE(101,*) R(0,1)

END PROGRAM
```

Comment: Why don't you just show us the code in question?  Would be a bit easier to help you with a solution.

Comment: @JLH  The code is quite long though which is why I didn't post a complete/working verifiable example code. However if you still suggest OK

Comment: Perhaps not all, just enough to give us a clue how to help you.

Comment: Drop them both in a file, then write a function at the top to select which to run. Or better yet just drop one in, add the different line and select.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks for the help. That sounds logical to me.  How do you suggest putting them both, or just 1, in a file?  Right now I have two different .f90 files.

Comment: @JLH Updated the post as you suggested, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the run-time approach.  You have an interactive query of which version you want to run, then an IF statement that selects one of the two alternative statements based on that.  Another version of this is to read the choice from the command line using the intrinsic GET_COMMAND_ARGUMENT.

A compile-time approach would be to use the preprocessor to select one statement or the other by defining a symbol (e.g., SYM) or not with your compile command (-DSYM), that using #ifdef SYM, #else, #endif to select which Fortran statement to compile.

Some code fragments.  Declare choice as an integer and filename as a string.

```
read (*, '( "Input choice: " )',  advance="no" )  choice
```

or

```
call GET_COMMAND_ARGUMENT ( 1, string )
read (string, *)  choice
```

then:

```
if (choice /=1 .AND. choice /=2 ) then
   write (*, *) "bad choice"
   stop
end if

if (choice == 1) then
   filename = "FileOne.txt"
else
   filename = "FileTwo.txt"
end if

open (file=filename, ....
```

and similar IF statement to setup the initial condition.

Or instead you can include or not `-DCHOICEONE` in your compilation command and use preprocessor lines:

```
#ifdef CHOICEONE
   filename = "FileOne.txt"
#else
   filename = "FileTwo.txt"
#endif
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you provide actual FORTRAN code?  I am not sure how to implement any of what you suggest.  If I use an IF statement to choose the initial condition, what about the names of all my files in the OPEN lines?  Do I have to move all the OPEN file lines into the IF statement as well? Also, you mention examples already here on stackoverflow - where?

Comment: Use two IF statements, one for the filename and the other for the initial condition.

Comment: @JeffFaraci You really need to take a crack at it yourself.

Comment: @Holmz Do you have any useful suggestions?

Comment: @M.S.B. What should the IF statements contain? I am not sure how to use an IF statement that refers to an actual FORTRAN file name. How do I construct an interactive query? Can you provide any code? Otherwise your answer may sound nice to somebody who is familiar with this stuff but this really isn't too helpful for me as a beginner. Thanks